# Whats the intermediate step of the partial derivatives in this Gaussian error propagation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, error-propagation, gaussian

I tried it, but I am not sure how to derive frac{\del m}{\del e} partially and get the desired result of \frac{1}{\frac{e}{m}}. What is the intermediate step leading to this derivative?
Note that `m=\frac{e}{e/m}`
[image]

Comment: There are some details that you have not given us. It sounds like you are talking about writing $m=\frac{e}{\frac{e}{m}}$ and then understanding $u=e$ and $v=\frac{e}{m}$ and  then treating these as independent variables in your propagation. In this case it is as simple as $m=\frac{u}{v}$ so $\frac{\partial m}{\partial u}=\frac{1}{v}$. The issue is about the interpretation of $u$ and $v$ as being independent variables in the first place, which could *possibly* make sense in certain experimental scenarios but is pretty fishy on its face.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir highly appreciate your answer it helped me understand it!! Have a nice day!